# Have data in addition to source code when making crates?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

There's a problem I am running often with rust crates.

Say I am making a crate that requires some data. For example it might need images, or csv files, or binary executables compiled from C++, shader files...

That create will be consumed by another crate, but for it to work correctly it must be able to access the data it defines. But since it can be installed in arbitrary places depending on environment, it is not easy to deduce where to search for the external files the crate needs.

How do you specify non source data for a crate?

Comment: Are you asking assuming you cannot bake it into the executable with `include_str!()`/`include_bytes!()`?

Comment: the problem with those is that they make the executable quite big and are not always super ergonomic. For example if the file is a dynamic libe, you likely need to write the file to disk in the first place to then read it back with a linker. So now your executable is now carrying both the original data and the loaded data from disk.

Comment: Another example is, you may have a dependency that only know how to look for files on disk, so even if you have the data in RAM already you still ahve to write it to disk for your utility to find it.

Comment: For libraries it's common to use `pkg-config`/`vcpkg`. In general, environment variables can work. Since cargo is designed around specifically source code, it's usually not used for distributing non-source data.